# angularjs Nan Is Appearing if textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating a web app in which I am calculating a `$scope` variable with a `textbox`, but if a user put `textbox` empty or if a user don't enter anything on `textbox` the result is coming `NaN` here is my code

```
<input type="text" ng-model="amount1" ng-blur="amountchange(amount1)" />
{{total}}
```

And in my **controller** I have

```
$scope.amountchange = function () {
    $scope.total = parseInt($scope.amount1) + parseInt($scope.total);
}
```

I want to get rid off the `NaN` which is apearing if the textbox is empty

Here is a fiddle that I created for better understanding

**[CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/XNVj3/2251/)**

Comment: [`$scope.total = parseInt($scope.amount1) + parseInt($scope.total) || 200;`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/XNVj3/2252/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Use*

```
$scope.constant = 200;     //Define other variable to persist constants
$scope.total = $scope.constant;        //Initialize total 
$scope.amountchange = function() {        
    var amount1 = parseInt($scope.amount1, 10) || 0; //parse amount if its invalid set it to zero
    $scope.total = $scope.constant + amount1; //update total
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/mcyvrckk/2/)

Comment: but if i add 500 in 200(it is becoming 700) but when i remove 500 from textbox it is still 700(not decreasing) it should be 200 if i remove 500

Comment: `$scope.total` this scope variable is just an example, but it can be 500 or 1000, will it work with that???